# Execute self-extracting bash script (with binary data appended) w/o saving it first

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, bash-scripting, tail

I have a self-extracting bash script (binary data appended to the end) like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)

ARCHIVE_START_LINE=$(...) # <omitted>

# extracting data archive into a temporary directory
tail -n+$ARCHIVE_START_LINE $0 | tar xzv -C $TMPDIR

# <ACCESSING_ARCHIVED_RESOURCES>

exit 0

# <BINARY_DATA_ARCHIVE>
```

The script is hosted remotely at `https://<omitted>/script.sh`

I want to pull the script and execute it locally.

As I'm using `tail` within the script passing it current file name as an argument, I cannot do:

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://<omitted>/script.sh)"
```

Of course I can first save it into a temporary file, e.g.:

```bash
TMP=$(mktemp); curl -fsSL https://<omitted>/script.sh > $TMP; sh $TMP; rm $TMP
```

But... any neater way?

Comment: I don't see how this could ever be possible without some file. Maybe some clever trick with a FiFo, but that's still a file. Why don't you store the binary data as a variable in the script and so avoid the need for `tail`? Wouldn't that be a decent solution?

Comment: Does storing it in a temporary file have awkward problems like it might be scanned by anti-malware software?

Comment: Why do not use "standard" `shar` file? https://www.mankier.com/1/shar

Comment: @AndrewMorton nothing too sinister - just an env setup script. :) It won't be catastrophic to download the file first and then run it locally. Just thought if I could maybe avoid it. I have very limited experience with bash and I wouldn't be surprised if it was something trivial.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I want the resulting script to both extract the archive and then run the scripts from that extracted archive. Seemed easiest to just write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the structure of the script slightly so you don't need `tail`. Just save the data as a variable instead:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## begin data dump
read -r -d '' archive_data <<'EoF'
<BINARY_DATA_ARCHIVE>
EoF
## end data dump

export tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

# extracting data archive into a temporary directory
printf '%s' "$archive_data" | tar xzv -C "$tmpdir"

exit 0
```

Comments:

- **This will not work if the data archive can contain NUL (`\0`)**.
- Note the single quotes around `'EoF'`, these ensure that any `$` won't be expanded to wrong variable names.
- I also changed your variables to lower case as it is bad practice to use caps for shell variables since, by convention, global environment variables are capitalized and this can lead to naming collisions and unexpected bugs. Use lower case for your variables and capitalize global envs only whenever possible.
- I changed `mktemp` to `mktemp -d` since you seem to be trying to create a directory and without `-d` the command `mktemp` makes a file.

You should now be able to do something like

```
curl -fsSL https://<omitted>/script.sh | bash
```

Comment: What if the binary data contains null byte(s)? Will your method work?

Comment: Ah, very good point @KamilMaciorowski and no, I don't think it will work. I added a disclaimer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I tried this approach, but am getting an error trying to extract archive: "tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format". Seems I do indeed have some `\0` in my data archive (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBOdu.png), but why does it actually matter?

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits ah, if you have `\0`, those are removed by bash when assigning to a variable. Shell variables cannot contain nulls. Try `var=$(printf 'a\0b')` and then `printf '%s\n' "$var" | od -c` and you will see that `$var` is just `ab` with no `\0`. You'll also get an error message: "bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input".